# How to get a particular text from the text box

Tags: javascript, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a scenario, where I need to get a certain text from the text box. I understand that the following code will return the entire text in the text box. Is there a way to get a particular line of text from the text box, and not the entire text? Thanks!

```
WebElement config = driver.findElement(By.id("adFragment"));
//Assertion     
verifyDisplay(config.getAttribute("value"), By.id("adFragment"));
```

The HTML:

```
<section style="display: block;">
        <div>
            <h2 class="no-margin">tag source</h2>
            <div>
                <textarea placeholder="Your HTML fragment here" rows="30" id="adFragment" name="adFragment" style="height:400px; width:800px;"></textarea><br>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: `getAttribute` would return the entire text in the textbox... can you please explain what is that u need from the text box.

Comment: @Programmer, I need to fetch a dynamically changing url link as a String...

Comment: Your questions is unclear. Have a read through this https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and adjust it accordingly.

Comment: You did not read the link I provided. If you want only part of the retrieved text, you will have to use String functions to slice it.

Comment: @familyGuy your question and the comment is again not clear, so do you want URL of the page or text from textbox?

Comment: @Programmer I sincerely apologize, but I want TEXT from the textbox...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following, I have not tried it. But I assume it would help you

```
String eleValue = config.getAttribute("value");
if(eleValue.contains("YourRequiredText")){  
     //Either you can put the required text in variable by splitting the string or mark it as pass  
     Assert.assertTrue(true);  
}
```